# hls.js - how to increase the preloaded buffer size

Tags: ffmpeg, video.js, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, clappr

I am generating hls content using ffmpeg from a remote src and I keep experience lagging that I do not understand in the browser.

For instance, even though there are say **out8.ts, out9.ts** ... hls.js player will be on say **out7.ts and not load out8.ts or out9.ts.**

It waits until out7.ts **has almost finished** playing and then it tries to load the **out.m3u8** which will contain out8.ts and possibly out9.ts. But it does this so late, it eventually leads to lagging. I am doing this on localhost and in an efficient manner.

This seems to repeat itself once it starts to occur.

How can I make hls.js **ask for the m3u8 more often** and **buffer what ever is present**? Or as much as possible?

**Also if there** is already say 1-10.ts files, how can I make hls.js start on not the last one ( although closer to live ) but maybe on 5.ts so it won't run into this tight deadline issues concerning the next updated m3u8 and possibly lenghty 11.ts preventing it from buffering it?

My options:

```
    new Hls({
            autoStartLoad: true,
            debug: App.isDevelopment(),
            manifestLoadingTimeOut : 60000,
            /*manifestLoadingMaxRetry : 9,*/
            manifestLoadingRetryDelay : 500,
            levelLoadingTimeOut : 60000,
            /*levelLoadingMaxRetry : 9,*/
            levelLoadingRetryDelay : 500,

            fragLoadingTimeOut : 60000,
            /*fragLoadingMaxRetry : 6,*/
            fragLoadingRetryDelay : 250,
            startFragPrefetch : true
    });
```

Is there any difference in **using clapper** instead of hls.js regarding controlling such things?

Comment: Have you found a good solution for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag you are experiencing may be down to the segment duration. For a live stream, a short duration can cause more frequent requests for the playlist, which can cause additional network traffic. Apple recommends 10 seconds but (I believe) ffmpeg uses a default of 2 seconds.  You can set the segment duration with the `-hls_time` option if you are using ffmpeg's hls muxer or with the `-segment_time` option if you are using the segment one. I'd try this first.

The HLS specification specifies that the time between [reloading the playlist](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-18#section-6.3.4) is determined by the target duration of the segments, so I guess the player must adhere to this if it is to be compliant with the spec.

You can use the EXT-X-START tag to [start playing the video at a specific point in time](http://hlsbook.net/how-to-start-playing-a-video-at-a-specific-point-in-time/).

Comment: Yes, I have used hls_time and experimented with various lengths. I think the main problem is that I wasn't getting fixed lengths for each segments. Some would be 10 seconds and others 8 or 12 which would cause lag in the latter case, since it won't be ready when the first 10 seconds has elapsed. 

This helped get consistent lengths though: 

-x264-params scenecut=0 -x264opts keyint_min=100 -g 100 -r 20 -framerate 20

Answer (score 0):

Try to use maxBufferLength.This is the guaranteed buffer length hls.js will try to reach, regardless of maxBufferSize.